# Hibernate unidirectional One-to-many with multiple constraints

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, one-to-many

Suppose I have some generic tables `apple`, `orange` etc and a table `note` which contains notes about a row in one of my generic table. The note is stored by saving the `entity_type` (e.g. the table name) and `entity_id` (e.g. the id of the row).

I'm trying to make a unidirectional One-to-Many mapping from `apple` to `note`. Effectively creating this relationship:

```
SELECT * 
FROM apple f 
INNER JOIN note n 
ON f.id = n.entity_id
AND n.entity_type = 'apple'
```

I've been trying something like:

```
@Entity
public class Apple {

    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "entity_type = 'apple'")
    private Set<Note> changeNotes = new HashSet<>();
```

Which isn't working (error is `@WhereJoinTable on an association without join table`). Any ideas?

Update:
I think this is the sort of thing I"m trying to do https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_02/ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins.html
However hibernate is looking for a column instead of just using the string...

Comment: Are you restricted to mapping entities to an existing (ugly-sounding) database design, or are you free to modifies the database structure?  Any time a table needs to contain other tables' names as data, you can anticipate serious problems.

Comment: JPA has provisions for [entity polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html) that may provide a firmer foundation on the Java side, and may point you toward a more supportive structure on the DB side as well.

Comment: The database structure is locked in unfortunately

Comment: Use `Where`, not `WhereJoinTable`.